# Vuejs changes order of json_encoded array, when decodes it back from props in vuejs component

Tags: json, laravel, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Php:

```
$json_string = "{
    "26":{"blabla":123,"group_id":1,"from":"27.08.2018","to":"02.09.2018"},
    "25":{"blabla":124,"group_id":1,"from":"20.08.2018","to":"26.08.2018"},
    "24":{"blabla":125,"group_id":1,"from":"20.08.2018","to":"26.08.2018"}
    }"
```

my.blade.php template:

```
<my-component :records={{ $json_string }}></my-component>
```

MyComponent.vue:

```
export default {
    props: ['records'],
...
mounted: function () {
        console.log(this.records);
}
```

Output is:

```
{__ob__: Observer}
24:(...)
25:(...)
26:(...)
```

And when I use v-for, records in my table in wrong order (like in console.log output).

What I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I figured out 1 thing:

When I do json_encode on collection where indexes are from 0 till x, than json string is: `[{some data}, {some data}]`

But if I do `->get()->keyBy('id')` (laravel) and than json_encode, json string is:

```
 { "26":{some data}, "25":{some data}, "24":{some data} }
```

Then how I understood, issue is in different outer brackets.

Comment: chrome dev tools formats the output and automatically sort stuff like this. So what you see in console may be different then the actual data.

Comment: I wrote, that v-for prints my rows in a table also in wrong direction

Comment: That's because when you wrote that string and sent it through JSON, it orders it by keys naturally. Just reverse them.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy, Yes, it will work in my case, but if I will pass 25 24 26?

Answer (score 0):

In Javascript keys of objects have no order. If you need a specific order then use arrays.

Answer (score 0):

Here is documentation for `keyBy` Laravel method: https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/collections#method-keyby

I wanted to have ids for rows data to fast and easy access without iterating over all rows and check if there is somewhere key Id which is equals with my particular Id.

**Solution**: not to use keyBy method in Laravel and pass json string to Vue component like following `[{some data}, {some data}]` (as I described in my Question Edit section) - this will remain array order as it used to be.

I found this short and elegant way how to do this, instead of writing js function by myself:

Its `find()` method: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

**Example**:

```
let row = records.find( record => record.id === idToFind );
```